# Show a image on popup, jqm 1.3.2

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to get a picture and show it with a popup of jQuery Mobile 1.3.2. The name of the image I get from  a table and I push  on a js variable . The image (the file) are on a related path in server side ("../uploads/thumbs/”) .   When I clik on button, launch the popup but don’t show the picture, it show a  complete path (this path is correct ) , but not the image. Sorry I´m beginner, any idea?...

PHP

```
<?php
     …
        $n_fich = $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($row['n_fich']);
    …
?>
```

HTML

```
    <script>
            var baseurl = "../uploads/thumbs/";
            var nom_fich_img_ofert = '<?php echo $n_fich ;?>';
            var path_img_ofert= document.write ('\"' + baseurl + nom_fich_img_ofert + '\"' ); 
         </script>

<a href="#popupfotomioferta" data-role="button" 
data-icon="grid" data-mini="true" data-rel="popup" 
id="imagePopupLink">Imagen de la Oferta
</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupfotomioferta" data-overlay-theme="a" 
data-theme="d" data-corners="false">

 <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" 
data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" 
class="ui-btn-right">Cerrar</a>
<img class="popphoto" src="path_img_ofert" 
style="max-height:512px;" alt="picture">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var path_img_ofert= document.write ('\"' + baseurl + nom_fich_img_ofert + '\"' );
```

try

```
$(".popphoto").attr('src',  baseurl + nom_fich_img_ofert );
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/b8yqz/)**

Comment: Hi ezanker. I´ve try and its works!!!!, thank you very much and thaks a lot for your demo code. My Best Regards :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer so others know the question has been resolved.